# Rails 5.2 Asset Pipeline images not loading on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am working with a Rails 5.2 application

Locally I added a new image to `app/assets/images/my-file-name.jpg`

and then in my .erb file I reference it using

`<%= image_tag "my-file-name.jpg" %>`

Then when I deploy to Heroku I run the following steps locally

1. `rake assets:clobber` <!-- this destroys the `public/assets` folder as expected
2. `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` this creates a new `public/assets` folder but now each of the files within the assets folder have a hash after their name.  So my file `my-file-name.jpg` has become `my-file-name-{BigLongCacheBustingHashHere}.jpg`
3. git push staging <-- Deploy to my staging environment and check that the log says assets compiling -- all good.
4. Check staging environment if the image is being served and I notice that the app cannot find my image because my `<%= image_tag my-file-name.jpg %>` is still producing a static html link WITHOUT the hash.  It looks like this `<img src="my-file-name.jpg">` when I believe it should be producing a tag that looks like `<img src="my-file-name-{BigLongCashBustingHashHere}.jpg"`

Why do you think the <%= image_tag %> is not producing production friendly urls?
I can see that it is working elsewhere in the app so not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I lost hours of my life on this.  Rails assets does not like .jpeg extensions and will flat out ignore them in production.  So I just changed the file name to `my-file-name.jpg` and now Rails is happy